# How to find $a_3$ and $a_4$ if $a_1$ and $a_2$ are given in a $4$×$4$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4$ be the four columns of a $4$×$4$ matrix $A$. If its reduced row echelon form is given by:$$\left(\begin{matrix} 1 & 0 & 2 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 & 4 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{matrix}\right)$$
>   and it is known that:$$a_1=\begin{bmatrix} -3 \\ 5 \\ 2 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix},a_2=\begin{bmatrix} 4 \\ -3 \\ 7 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix}$$
>   then find $a_3$ and $a_4$.

Can anyone give hints to solve this problem.

Comment: Hint: How do the nonzero rows of the rref relate to the row space of the original matrix?

Comment: It might help you if you notice that the rows of the matrix $A$ must be linear combinations of the vectors $(1,0,2,1)$, $(0,1,1,4)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have suggestion for you. Suppose that 
$a_3 = [u \quad  y \quad  v \quad  z]^T \quad a_4 = [u' \, y' \,v' \, z']^T$. By using the Gassian Elemination, we obtain the reduced row of the matrix A. From this we can find columns $a_3$,and $ a_4$.